# problema con componente angular

Tags: html, nodejs, angular

Hola buenas tengo un problema y espero por  favor me puedan ayudar.
estoy desarrollando con el stack mean dentro de la base de datos como modelo tengo esto.

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const documentosShcema = new Schema(
    {

      documentTitle: { type: String, required: false },
      documentAuthor: { type: String, required: false },
      documentDescription: { type: String, required: false },
      documentUser: { type: String, required: false },
      documentDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      documentType: { type: String, required: false },
      documentUrl: { type: String, required: false },
      documentArea: { type: String, required: false },
    },
    {
      versionKey: false,
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );

module.exports = mongoose.model("Documento", documentosShcema);
```

al modelo le agregué el ultimo dato hace poco y es lo que me trae problemas el dato documentArea

en la seccion del back end todo bien sin embargo si es que llegase a ser util les dejo el controlador

```
documentoCtrl.uploadFile = async(req, res, next)=>{

    const documento = new Documento({
        documentTitle: req.body.documentTitle,
        documentAuthor: req.body.documentAuthor,
        documentDescription: req.body.documentDescription,
        documentUser: req.userId,
        documentType: 'Documento',
        documentUrl: req.file.path,
        documentArea: req.body.documentArea,

      });
      
      await documento.save();

}
```

lo que realiza el controlador es subir un archivo y sus datos, bueno viendo el front end que es la parte donde está el problema sucede lo siguiente.

en primera instancia tengo mi servicio al cual hace poco le añadí el dato documentArea les dejo mi servicio:

```
  createDocument(
    documentTitle: string,
    documentAuthor: string,
    documentDescription: string,
    documentArea: string,
    file: File,
    ) {

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('documentTitle', documentTitle);
    fd.append('documentAuthor', documentAuthor);
    fd.append('documentDescription', documentDescription);
    fd.append('documentArea', documentArea);
    fd.append('file', file);
    return this.http.post(this.URL+'/documentos', fd);
    
  }

  getTasksArea() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.URL + '/tasks');
  }
```

esto lo uso en mi componente de esta manera:

```
  uploadDocument(documentTitle: HTMLInputElement, documentAuthor: HTMLInputElement, documentDescription: HTMLTextAreaElement, documentArea: HTMLOptionElement){
    this.documentoService
      .createDocument(
        documentTitle.value, 
        documentAuthor.value, 
        documentDescription.value,
        documentArea.value,  
        this.file
        )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.router.navigate(['/documentos'])
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    return false;
  }
```

y lo llamo de la siguiente manera en mi html

```
 <form (submit)="uploadDocument(documentTitle, documentAuthor, documentDescription, documentArea)">
```

ahora el problema que surge es que me arroja un error el cual indica que document area no se encuentra en el componente pero si está en el componente, está en el servcio tambien y en el modelo y no se por qué aparece ese error si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

les dejo el error que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cabe destacar que sin ese ultimo dato la aplicación funciona pero al agregarlo me arroja un error.

Comment: Es importante que pongas el código del componente.

Comment: lo que te esta ocurriendo es que al ejecutar el submit:

    `<form (submit)="uploadDocument(documentTitle, documentAuthor, documentDescription, documentArea)">`

angular esta buscando cada una de esas variables en el componente y la que no encuentra es: `documentArea`.

por eso te solicitan el codigo del componente.

Comment: el codigo del componente que se utiliza al realizar esa opcion es uploadDocument lo dejé en la publicación pero si está documentArea dentro del componente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error estaba en el componente el la part de html

la correcta forma de tomar el dato al estar dentro de un menu deplegable era la siguiente

```
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" [(ngModel)]="taskSelected" (change)="onSelect2($event.target.value)" #documentArea required >
                    <option id="document" *ngFor="let task of tasks" [value]="task.name" >
                       {{task.name}}         
                    </option>                
                </select>
```

los resultados por parte del controlador los guardé en una lista y el dato seleccionado lo manejé por un string.